# How do I install the ASUS USB-AC51 Wireless Adapter?

Tags: wireless, adapter

I do  not know how to install the ASUS USB-AC51  wireless adapter.  I am not very good with

Comment: Please [follow the instructions for Wifi issue diagnosis](/q/425155/) and [edit] your question to include or link to the results.

Comment: this adapter only works for kernels up to 2.6, i tried in vain to get it up and running on 14.04. asus needs to let customers know it onlly works on legacy os's.

Comment: @duanestroh Does Asus have any documentation to this effect?

Answer (score 5):

I struggled to make it work on modern distributions, but since Kernel 4.19 there is native support for mt7610u. Fedora 30 and Ubuntu 19.04 has this kernel version.

These distributions should work without any additional effort.

Comment: Just purchased one and it works out of the box without any configuring on Ubuntu 19.04

Answer (score 4):

There is a newer Linux driver for the underlying chipset "MT7610U USB" here:
https://github.com/maage/mt7610u_wifi/tree/some_changes

This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04.4, whereas the MediaTek drivers did not. The above is a fork of the MediaTek drivers which fixes the compilation errors and warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Download the linux driver from [here](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/wireless/USB-AC51/UT_USB_AC51_3001_Linux.zip). The instructions are included in the zip folder and following them will install the driver. Reboot the system after installation to get your USB adapter working.

You can also refer to the user manual which you can download from [here](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/wireless/USB-AC51/E8743_USB_AC51_Manual.zip).

Answer (score 1):

I bought this adapter yesterday, and at first it seemed like nothing helps to make it work.

Luckily, I found **this**: [TP-Link AC600 driver on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726569/tp-link-ac600-driver-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-x64)

*P.S. It is a guide for TP-Link's driver, but it seems to do the trick for ASUS USB-AC51.*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.

Comment: Oh sorry, I will be more careful in the future with that :)