# TP-Link AC600 driver on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64

Tags: wireless

I need some help with installing these drivers: http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/Archer-T2U.html#Driver

Some info:

```
$ uname -r
3.13.0-76-generic

$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

Comment: Notice it says it is for kernel versions 2.6 through 3.16? What is your kernel version? From the terminal: `uname -r` What is your device? From the terminal: `lsusb` Please edit your question to add these details.

Comment: uname -r:
 3.13.0-76-generic

lsusb:
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp.

Comment: sorry, do not know why no linebraks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Connect to internet by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible. Then run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential linux-headers-generic
git clone https://github.com/Myria-de/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.git
cd mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916
make
sudo make install
sudo cp RT2870STA.dat  /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/RT2870STA.dat
```

Reboot.

You will have to re-install it after each kernel upgrade. Please you keep the driver folder mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916, then it will be quite easy.

You will need to run only:

```
cd mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you! Do you think this driver will be added to Ubuntu in the future? I also think there is little diod in this module, but it seems not to be working...

Comment: Diod is working, sorry)) Excellent!

Comment: doesn't seem to work on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @liang Please start your own new question. I am not at all certain it can be made to work in 16.04 and later, but I'm very happy to try.

Comment: Fresh ones for this shit:

 http://github.com/xtknight/mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes

    
 http://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u