# Cannot Install ASUS USB-AC51 Wireless on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, asus

I am at my wit's end. I have a Dell Vostro 1700 laptop, maybe six or seven years old. It has an internal Broadcom 4321 wireless adapter, that I got running using the legacy B43 installer. Download speeds with this adapter stink. Ookla Speedtest gives me less than 1Mbs down, but nearly 6Mbs up (that just ain't right). The Broadcom yielded approximately the same values when I had Win 10 running (poorly) on this machine. While the laptop was still running Win 10, I bought the ASUS USB-AC51 wireless adapter. After getting drivers for it, download speeds increased by a factor of 30. So, that tells me that there's no hardware impediment to using the AC51.

I have tried everything from the top 3 or 4 search results for installing the AC51 on Ubuntu 16.04, to no avail.

`sudo lshw -C` network gives me this:

```
*-network               
  description: Wireless interface
  product: BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n
  vendor: Broadcom Corporation
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
  logical name: wlp12s0
  version: 03
  serial: 00:1d:d9:45:70:f8
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
  configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=10.60.33.250 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
  resources: irq:17 memory:f9ffc000-f9ffffff memory:f0000000-f00fffff
*-network
  description: Ethernet interface
  product: BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX
  vendor: Broadcom Corporation
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
  logical name: eth0
  version: 02
  serial: 00:19:b9:82:04:5b
  size: 10Mbit/s
  capacity: 100Mbit/s
  width: 32 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
  configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=b44 driverversion=2.0 duplex=half latency=64 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
  resources: irq:17 memory:f9bfe000-f9bfffff
*-network DISABLED
  description: Wireless interface
  physical id: 1
  logical name: ra0
  capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
  configuration: broadcast=yes driver=RALINK WLAN multicast=yes wireless=Ralink STA
```

lsusb gives me this:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy (MTP)
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0b05:17d1 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AC51 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter [Mediatek MT7610/Ralink RT2870]
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 1532:0034 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0a5c:4503 Broadcom Corp. Mouse (Boot Interface Subclass)
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4502 Broadcom Corp. Keyboard (Boot Interface Subclass)
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 413c:8126 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 355 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

So, `lsusb` sees the AC-51, but the adapter doesn't light up, even after compiling and installing the driver from MT7612U_DPO_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.1_20140718, doing a `make clean` when that didn't work, then installing the driver from RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.20_16317_20160108.

`lshw` sees the internal Broadcom wireless adapter, but also a disabled wireless adapter that it doesn't identify. I'm guessing this is the AC-51.

P.S. As soon as I can login, I'll post output from the wireless troubleshooting script to DropBox.

Comment: You could try `rfkill` command (`rfkill list`, `rfkill block`, `rfkill unblock`) to see for example if disabling the internal adapter has any effect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. 
Output from rfkill list:
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
I'll give blocking the internal a short, but it's going to disconnect me, naturally.

Comment: Here's the link to the output from the wireless troubleshooting script:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/73b2u83cmm7kivy/wireless-info.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: I have Ubuntu 14.04, so I don't know will this help, but if you are still having the problem, you might as well give it a try. This helped me (although it's TP-Link's driver): http://askubuntu.com/questions/726569/tp-link-ac600-driver-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-x64 Hopefully that helps you as well!

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Linux Kernel 4.19, the Asus USB-AC51 is supported.

See https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.19/drivers/net/wireless/mediatek/mt76/mt76x0/usb.c#L30

You might wanna give it a try.

> (Try install all the following debian packages:
>   linux-image-unsigned-4.19.0-041900-generic_4.19.0-041900.201810221809_amd64.deb
>    linux-modules-4.19.0-041900-generic_4.19.0-041900.201810221809_amd64.deb
>    from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19/ )