# How to install AC600 wifi adapter in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: drivers, wireless

This dual-range dongle is a TP-Link AC660 [not AC300] Archer T2UH, chipset MT7610U

I have followed several internet suggestions as how to install MT7510U.

The `lsusb` is:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0930:6545 Toshiba Corp. Kingston DataTraveler 102/2.0 / HEMA Flash Drive 2 GB / PNY Attache 4GB Stick
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0930:6545 Toshiba Corp. Kingston DataTraveler 102/2.0 / HEMA Flash Drive 2 GB / PNY Attache 4GB Stick
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 04a9:220e Canon, Inc. CanoScan N1240U/LiDE 30
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 03ee:6901 Mitsumi SmartDisk FDD
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Thank you for your help.

The solutions I have found on the Internet either do not compile (possibly because they are for earlier kernels) or--where they seem to compile--just do not work.  Any suggestions gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Posting the exact make/model and especially chipset will be gratefully appreciated. Also a description of your issue would be great.

Comment: What is AC300? Is it a USB dongle?

Comment: If you don't tell us what you tried, we'll probably just tell you to try it again! Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/726569/tp-link-ac600-driver-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-x64